# Format.name$ fails with cyrrillic unicode and bibtex8

Tags: bibtex

It seems that `bibtex.exe` and `bibtex8.exe` fails to format names in a list of persons (e.g., of authors) when using utf8 encoding if `author` contains cyrillic letters. For example the following directive in a `.bst` style

```
  author #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
```

fails for the following bibliographic record

```
@BOOK{Ponomarenko86,
  title        = {Основы создания гибких атоматизированных производств},
  author       = {Л. А. Пономаренко and Л. В. Адамович
                  and В. Т. Музычук and  А. Е. Гридасов},
  editor       = {Б. Б. Тимофеева},
  address      = {К.},
  publisher    = {Техніка},
  year         = {1986},
  pagetotal    = {144},
  language     = {russian},
}
```

However, changing formatting of `author` field to alternative form

```
 author       = {Пономаренко, Л. А. and Адамович, Л. В. 
                  and Музычук, В. Т.  and  Гридасов, А. Е. },
```

produces expected result. Neverthelles formatting of first names with `f.` modifier still fails as in

```
  author #1 "{f.~}{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
```

I tried to invoke `bibtex8` using various `.csf` files and, in particular,

```
bibtex8 -B -c utf8cyrillic.csf file
```

I understand that neither `bibtex` nor `bibtex8` are intended for unicode but is there a remedy?

Comment: No: `bibtex8` deals only with single byte encodings. You can try `bibtexu`, but it's unmaintained and possibly buggy.

Comment: Did you try with `biblatex`+ `biber`? The latter understands `utf8`.

Comment: @Bernard: Yes, this is good option, but I am a maintainer of the GOST package for Bibtex which stiill has many users writing in  Russian. Note also that scientific journals don't like biblatex.